# How can I determine the dates on which separate baseball teams had the same result?

Tags: baseball, statistics

For my interest, I would like to know how many times the Rockies, Angels, and Yankees won on the same day in 2017.  Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is extremely limited in scope and unlikely to aid any future users.

Comment: @Nij I expanded the scope a little, and wouldn't mind providing an answer to how to do this (using baseball-reference and a spreadsheet). Thinking teaching spreadsheet skills to sports fans might be of some use?  Not sure it's useful enough to be on topic, but will defer to you guys for thoughts.

Comment: I think, if you make that much more obviously the purpose of the question, with an example using three random teams like the Rockers, Angels and Yankees, that would be a great question.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest That's exactly what [this meta discussion](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/583) is about..."how to find stats on [a topic]?" Your statement about teaching sports fans spreadsheet [and research] skills is on point with said discussion.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ Seems there's a Meta post for everything today!!! That's great! Still not sure what to make of Meta posts in the long run, as they often don't seem to reach a concluding "ok, then this is what we'll do", and typically, beyond a comment or two and votes, not sure what more I'd contribute. But will do my best to help :-)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Thanks for your assistance. Although we may have a reputation of not being active on meta or not coming to solid conclusions, we have been more active as of late. It takes one user to make a difference and a community to stand by, reject, counter, and make decisions. With one willing to make a difference and an active community, this isn't an issue :)

Answer (score 2):

The Rockies, Angels, and Yankees all won this year on April 4, 22, 28, May 6, 14, 16, 21, and 22.

I found this by going to the Data section on Massey Ratings and pulled up the results of all baseball games this year (http://www.masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=294524&sub=14342&all=1&mode=3&format=0).

I copied the entire table to excel, and used Text to Columns to make the data usable; Fixed Width is the best to use for Massey data. Starting with a lookup table of dates, I then used CountIfs to see if a certain team won on that day, and counted the number of times those three teams won on the same day. Here is a screenshot of the end result:[image]

Formula used:

=CountIfs(Column of Dates, Specific Date, Column of Winners, Specific Winner).

This is used in the table on the right that returned either 0 or 1. The "All 3 Win?" column just asks if the sum of the row is equal to 3.